# TapGesture not recognized by UIWebView (Methods will not be called at all)

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

When I follow the answers I found on StackOverflow all I need to get my `UIWebView` recognize a `touch` is implementing the following:

**WebVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebVC : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *test;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureR;

- (void)handleTap:(id)sender;

@end
```

**WebVC.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.delegate = self;

    self.tapGestureR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    self.tapGestureR.delegate = self;
    [self.webView addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureR];
}

- (void)handleTap:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"tapDetected");
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return YES;
}
```

Do you know why I don't see the `NSLog`?
`Method` will not be called at all.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
self. webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Use userInteractionEnabled method and set to YES. I think it will be helpful to you.

**Edited:**

Use `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`  method in your WebVC.m class.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
     NSLog(@"shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer");
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Nope, added this line to `viewDidLoad` but no `NSLog` is shown on console.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [webview gestureRecognizers])){
       if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]){
         if (gesture.numberOfTapsRequired == 1) 
            [webview removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
       }
    }
```

then add your gesture. 
like you have previously done